# DOM and xpath query in a parsing HTML case

Tags: php, dom, xpath

Here is the HTML I would like to parse :

```
$html = '
<h1>title</h1>

<div id="main">

<div id="page">

<div class="article">
<h2><span>date1</span> <a href="link1">title1</a></h2>
<p>text1</p>
</div>

<div class="article">
<h2><span>date2</span> <a href="link2">title2</a></h2>
<p>text2</p>
</div>

</div>

</div>';
```

Here is what i would like to get :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [link] => link1
        [title] => title1
        [description] => description1
        [date] => date1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [link] => link2
        [title] => title2
        [description] => description2
        [date] => date2
    )

)
```

And here is my PHP :

```
$doc = new DOMDocument(); $doc->loadHTML($html); $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$nodes = $xpath->query("//div[@class='article']/h2/a");
$list = array(); $i = 0;

if($nodes)
{
foreach($nodes as $node) {

    if($node->getAttribute('href')) 
    { $link = $node->getAttribute('href'); $list[$i]['link'] = $link; }

    if($node->nodeValue) 
    { $title = $node->nodeValue; $list[$i]['title'] = $title; }

    if($node->nodeValue) 
    { $description = $node->nodeValue; $list[$i]['description'] = $description; }

    if($node->nodeValue) 
    { $date = $node->nodeValue; $list[$i]['date'] = $date; }

    $i++;
}
}

echo '<pre>';
echo print_r ($list);
echo '</pre>';
```

The result is OK for `link1`, `title1`, `link2`, `title2` but not for `description1`, `date1`, `description2`, `date2`.

I was looking for some specific cases close to mine in the PHP manual. But most of the time, everything is quite theoritical when it deals with DOMdocument. Could you please help me or suggest me some more concrete ressources ?

EDIT : here is the content of $node

```
DOMElement Object
(
[tagName] => a
[schemaTypeInfo] => 
[nodeName] => a
[nodeValue] => title1
[nodeType] => 1
[parentNode] => (object value omitted)
[childNodes] => (object value omitted)
[firstChild] => (object value omitted)
[lastChild] => (object value omitted)
[previousSibling] => (object value omitted)
[attributes] => (object value omitted)
[ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
[namespaceURI] => 
[prefix] => 
[localName] => a
[baseURI] => 
[textContent] => title1
)
1
DOMElement Object
(
[tagName] => a
[schemaTypeInfo] => 
[nodeName] => a
[nodeValue] => title2
[nodeType] => 1
[parentNode] => (object value omitted)
[childNodes] => (object value omitted)
[firstChild] => (object value omitted)
[lastChild] => (object value omitted)
[previousSibling] => (object value omitted)
[attributes] => (object value omitted)
[ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
[namespaceURI] => 
[prefix] => 
[localName] => a
[baseURI] => 
[textContent] => title2
)
1
```

Comment: Could you supply us with a `print_r($node);` from your foreach? that makes it easier to answer your question and would maybe answer it for yourself.

Comment: OK, print_r done, thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally i wouldn't work this way, but this is a solution for your problem, i'm fetching the article div instead of the anchor:

```
$aNodes = $xpath->query("//div[@class='article']");
$aList = array(); 
$i = 0;
if($aNodes){
    foreach($aNodes as $aNode) {
        $aDates = $aNode->getElementsByTagName('span');
        foreach ($aDates as $sDate){
            $aList[$i]['date'] = $sDate->nodeValue;
        }
        $aLinks = $aNode->getElementsByTagName('a');
        foreach ($aLinks as $sLink){
            $aList[$i]['link']  = $sLink->getAttribute('href');
            $aList[$i]['linktext'] = $sLink->nodeValue;
        }
        $aTexts = $aNode->getElementsByTagName('p');
        foreach ($aTexts as $sText){
            $aList[$i]['descript'] = $sText->nodeValue;
        }
        $i++;
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r ($aList);
echo '</pre>';
```

OR if you are sure the layout is always the same:

```
foreach($aNodes as $aNode) {
        $aList[$i]['date'] = $aNode->getElementsByTagName('span')->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $aList[$i]['link']  = $aNode->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->getAttribute('href');
        $aList[$i]['linktext']  = $aNode->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $aList[$i]['descript']  = $aNode->getElementsByTagName('p')->item(0)->nodeValue;
        $i++;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you ! :) How would you have worked ? I'm still interested in being more efficient or knowing better practices.

Comment: in my case, i would never be stuck with trying to read a html file. scraping is not my favourite thing to do :)